# Custom Doctrine DQL Function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm new to Symfony, so maybe my problem is very stupid but here it is :

I'm trying to define a custom doctrine DQL function but I can't get it work.

PHP

```
namespace MsfBundle\AST\Functions;


use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class Geo extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ComparisonExpression
     */
    private $latitude;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ComparisonExpression
     */    
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * Parse DQL Function
     * 
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser 
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->latitude = $parser->ComparisonExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->longitude = $parser->ComparisonExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * Get SQL 
     * 
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {

    return sprintf('(6366*acos(cos(radians(%s))*cos(radians(`%s`))*cos(radians(`%s`) -radians(%s))+sin(radians(%s))*sin(radians(`%s`))))',
    $this->latitude->leftExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
    $this->latitude->rightExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
    $this->longitude->rightExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker), 
    $this->longitude->leftExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
    $this->latitude->leftExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
    $this->latitude->rightExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker));
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
doctrine:
#...
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            dql:
                numeric_functions:
                    geo :MsfBundle\AST\Functions\Geo
```

And here's what I get :

> Fatal error: Class 'MsfBundle\AST\Functions\Geo' not found in /var/www/mcr/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php on line 3070

If you have any lead to help me get throught this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks !

Comment: could you tell me what is your class file path? I see you are not using your Vendor name.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a backslash in geo :MsfBundle\AST\Functions\Geo, should be geo :\MsfBundle\AST\Functions\Geo. Seems the class need an absolute reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it before here the result : Fatal error: Class '\MsfBundle\AST\Functions\Geo' not found in /var/www/mcr/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php on line 3070

Comment: in that case make sure you have the class in the file src/MsfBundle/AST/Functions/Geo.php, maybe it is just a typo. Normally, in Symfony2, the path is src/Acme/VendorBundle, Bundle is in the second path, not like you have, maybe the namespace is Msf\ASTBundle\Functions\Geo

Comment: I named my file GeoFunction.php, that was the problem... Thanks a lot !